# How can I loop through some divs that share a class and apply a unique id to them?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a set of divs that share a class name, but have no individual id. The order in which they show up in html is important and must be preserved. I need to be able to loop through the list of elements given by `document.getElementsByClassName(className);` and give them each a unique id in the form `"tile-1" "tile-2" etc`.

I thought something like this may work but I soon came to realise that this would not work:

```js
const getTiles = document.getElementsByClassName(tileClass);
  let n = 1;
  for (e in getTiles){
    let i = "tile-" + n;  
    e.setAttribute("id", i);
    n++;
}
```

I was hoping it would be as easy as each element in the array having the `setAttribute` applied to them but I was wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `let i = "tile-" +` —  isn't `n` missing from that?

Comment: `e in getTiles` should be `e of getTiles`. You're setting `e` to the indexes.

Comment: @Pointy Thx for pointing out, must've accidentally deleted it while pasting

Comment: Aren't you getting an error that says that `e.setAttribute` is not a function?

Comment: so why is that not working? Did you look in. the developer console?

Comment: @Barmar thanks that works now that i changed it to of

Comment: Did you do any basic debugging before posting here? Like adding `console.log(e)` to see why it was getting an error?

Comment: Try this:
const newElementArray = Array.from(documentquerySelectorAll('*'));
newElementArray.forEach((el, index) => el.setAttribute('id', i));

Comment: @Barmar yes, I did but it just said `e has no attribute id` and I didn't see that I put `in` instead of  `of`. I've been doing a lot of python recently so it was probably just habit

Answer (score 2):

try that

```js
let i = 1;
document.querySelectorAll('.post').forEach(el => {
  el.id = 'title-' + i;
  i++
})
```

```html
<div class="post">
</div>
<div class="post">
</div>
<div class="post">
</div>
<div class="post">
</div>
```

Comment: there is no need for `i`, forEach has an index

Comment: This is also a good solution, thanks

Comment: @espascarello, you're right ...forEach((el,index) => {... is shorter. There were an i, so I've kept it

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Barmar in the comments, I needed to use `of` instead of `in` in the for loop. Works as intended now.